# Oracle APEX Stacked bar chart with percentage values

Tags: oracle, bar-chart, oracle-apex, stacked-bar-chart

I'm looking for an option to get a stacked bar chart in oracle apex with percentage values. My stacked bar chart works with integral numbers (e.g.use 80 for 80%) but I can't find an option to add the %-symbol to the values afterwards. So I divided my values by 100 and changed 'Format' in 'Value' to percent what worked perfectly with just one series but returns wrong values with two series. With two series I get values for the columns which can be summed zu 100, surely no coincidence. But that is not what I want. My values should stay the same, so 0.9 should be 90% like with one series. I'm working with the page designer of Application Express 21.1.7.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please also add your source query so maybe we can help by manipulating the query like concating % symbol at the end of the select statement or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution but I found a work around and maybe it helps somebody: Use the divided 100 values (0,05 for 5 %) and change the 'Format' in 'Value' of the specific axis to 'currency' and use the pattern '# %'. This do not work with integral numbers (like 5 for 5 %) but perfectly otherwise.